# Include php, css and js files from subdomain

Tags: include, subdomain

so I need to include a couple of files from a subdomain from the main domain (my subdomain is admin.mydomain.com and targets to => mydomain.com/admin/), but I can't get to.

My public_html structure is

-admincp (empty, this is the subdomain)
-css
-js
-includes
-fonts
-images

I need to include all the css, js and some php files (which are in /includes/) in the subdomain index but for some reason it retrieves nothing using "/css/xxx.css".

I've tried using "/home/user/public_html/includes" (or css, or js) and actually worked, but the problem then is the file I need to include (the header for example) is like this:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ar">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $meta_description ?>" />
        <meta name="author" content="Gaspar Dip" />

        <title><?php echo $page_title ?></title>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/metro-bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/metro-bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/iconFont.min.css">

    </head>
    <body class="metro">

                <nav class="navigation-bar light">
            <div class="navigation-bar-content">
                <a href="#" class="element"><span class="icon-stats-2"></span> Estudio Benintendi</a>
                <span class="element-divider"></span>

                <a class="pull-menu" href="#"></a>
                <ul class="element-menu">
                    <li><a href="/inicio">Inicio</a><li>
                    <li><a href="/acercadelestudio">Acerca del estudio</a><li>
                    <li><a href="/enviarcurriculum">Enviar curriculum</a><li>
                    <li><a href="/contactenos">Contactenos</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="no-tablet-portrait">
                    <span class="element-divider"></span>
                    <div class="element input-element">
                        <form>
                            <div class="input-control text">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar...">
                                <button class="btn-search"></button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <?php if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){ ?>
                        <ul class="element-menu place-right">
                            <li><a href="/login">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/registro">Registrarse</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <?php }else{ ?>
                        <div class="element place-right">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                                <span class="icon-cog"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu place-right" data-role="dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/usuarios/logout">Salir</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <span class="element-divider place-right"></span>
                        <button class="element place-right">
                            <span class="icon-user-3"></span>
                            <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>
                        </button>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <span class="element-divider place-right"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
```

So those links targetting the .css files actually go to admincp.mydomain.com/css/xxx.css instead of mydomain.com/css/xxx.css

Did I explain myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly giving the absolute path can make difference.

I mean full path to the css link something like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo FULL_PATH_TO_CSS; ?>/css/xxx.css"/>
```

Comment: Indeed this would be the key, but I ended up deleting the subdomain so I could handle with relative paths like "../css/xxx.css".

Note that "FULL_PATH_TO_CSS" in a subdomain would be like "/home/user/public_html/css"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/xxx.css"/>
```

This is not tested.

Comment: The problem with that is that I use a general "header.php" for all the pages, including the main domain, so if I change the href like this, this won't work on mydomain.com. I use header.php everywhere in my main domain, for all the pages (<?php include("header.php") ?>)